Open HTML file everytime USB RFID reader detects a card (then input the RFID into one of the forms of html)
I want to make a script that runs in the background, so that everytime my RFID reader detects a card, it will open an HTML file. My RFID works as a keyboard emulator.
Optionally, I want to input the RFID automatically to one of the form of HTML file.
The HTML Form
I want the program to automatically inputs the RFID into the NFC ID form.
I tried using a random program I found and modified, but I can't seem to use the library.
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import webbrowser
import time

# Set up the keyboard listener
def on_press(key):
    try:
        # Check if the key press is from the RFID reader (e.g., a string of digits)
        if key.char.isdigit():
            # Get the RFID data (assuming it's a single string of digits)
            rfid_data = ''
            while True:
                key = keyboard.read_key()
                if key == Key.enter:
                    break
                rfid_data += key.char
            print(f"RFID data: {rfid_data}")

            # Open the HTML file
            webbrowser.open('upload-data\html-web-upload.html')

            # Optionally, input the RFID data into a form on the HTML file
            # using selenium or another library
            #...

    except AttributeError:
        pass

def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop the listener when the Esc key is pressed
        return False

# Create a keyboard listener
with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

I installed pynput with pip on cmd, but when I try to run the code on VSC, it shows error,
File "c:\xampp\htdocs\switch_ditekan\script_nfc.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pynput
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput'

It may be a problem with my environment path, as I am not well versed in configuring it.

Using keyboard to input the data is not really the best pattern to use.
I assume you already get the RFID data in your python program, also you'are able to open the html file.
I suggest you to use search params instead and get the data in js.
like this:
  webbrowser.open('upload-data\html-web-upload.html?rfid_key=<the the from RFID>')

then, in your html something like this:
    let params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    let rfid_key = params.get('rfid_key');
    if (rfid_key) { /* Do your stuff with the key here */}

